# ¿Cómo realizar programar una acción de MySQL cuando se crea un registro?

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo el siguiente problema. Tengo dos tablas en mi base de datos.

Una corresponde a salas de chat y la otra a mensajes de la sala de chat.

```
mysql> describe chat_salas;
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field              | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| sala_uuid          | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| usuario_comprador  | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| usuario_vendedor   | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| fecha_creacion     | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
+--------------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe chat_mensajes;
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| sala_uuid      | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| mensaje_uuid   | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| usuario        | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| mensaje        | text        | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| visto          | int(11)     | NO   |     | 0                 |       |
| fecha_creacion | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

El comportamiento es el siguiente: Alguien crea un nuevo registro en la tabla `chat_salas`. Lo que crea una nueva sala de chat con un UUID, después de esto pueden crear mensajes en esa sala de chat utilizando el UUID.

Mi problema es: Tengo que verificar que al crear una nueva sala de chat en `chat_salas` exista por lo menos un registro de mensaje correspondiente a la sala creada en los primeros 5 minutos, de no ser así eliminar la sala de chat.

Comment: ¿Has probado con un evento que se inicie cada 5 minutos?

Comment: No te sería útil verificarlo a través de un cron y el proceso hacerlo igual?

Comment: @Sr1871 si pensé que podría hacerlo con un cron de unix cada 5 minutos, pero el problema que yo le veo es que esto es por cada 5 minutos de cada registro individual. ¿O hay algo que no estoy captando por ahí?

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 4):

Te propongo una solución basada en eventos:

```
CREATE EVENT elimina_salas
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 MINUTE DO
  DELETE FROM chat_salas WHERE sala_uuid NOT IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT sala_uuid FROM chat_mensajes
    ) AND fecha_creacion < NOW()- INTERVAL 5 MINUTE;
```

Cada 5 minutos elimina las salas sin mensajes creadas hace más de 5 minutos. En el peor de los casos, dejará una sala 10 minutos activa sin mensajes. Si te resulta excesivo, puedes reducir el tiempo de barrido. Lo que tienes garantizado es que no te eliminará ninguna sala creada hace menos de 5 minutos.

Recuerda activar los eventos:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```